If $f(x): [0,4]\to\{-1,1,0\}$, find the number of functions $f(x)$ that are discontinuous at every integer and continuous at all other points.
I tried: If the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are taking the same values, we have $3\cdot 2$ ways to set the integer $1$ and its 'surroundings', and then if they have different values then $C^3_2\cdot 3$ ways. This gives us $6+9=15$ ways to set the integer $1$.
WLOG, if $2$ is to be mapped to the same value as the interval $(1,2)$ we have only $2$ possible values for the interval $(2,3)$. And if it is not to be mapped to the same value then we have $2\cdot 3$ ways to set $2$ and $(2,3)$. Giving us $2+6=8$ ways. Same process goes for $3$.
So until now have $15\cdot 8\cdot 8$. Then we multiply this with $2\cdot 2$ since there are $2$ options for $0$ and $4$ each in every case.
This gives us an answer of $15\cdot 8\cdot 8\cdot 4$.
I was asked to report the number of divisors, which is $36$ according to my answer. But the given number of divisors is $24$.
EDIT: Noticed a slight error in line 2. If $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ have different values, we'll have $2\cdot C^3_2\cdot 3$ ways and not $C^3_2\cdot 3$. Giving me a corrected value of $6+18=24$. And then $24\cdot 8\cdot 8 \cdot 4=2^{11}\cdot 3$ which indeed has 24 divisors.
I'll still appreciate better methods.

The problem can be reformulated as finding the number of $a \in \{-1,0,1\}^9$ such that $a_1\neq a_2$, $a_8 \neq a_9$ and for all $j \in \{3,5,7\}$ it doesn't happen that $a_{j-1}=a_j = a_{j+1}$. This comes from considering the function's value on each integer and on each interval between alternatively.
We can drop the ends and multiply the number of good inner $7$-tuples by $4$, since for each end we have $2$ possibilities given an inner tuple. The inner tuples can be counted with inclusion-exclusion using the sets $A_j = \{a=(a_2,\dots,a_8) | a_{j-1}=a_j = a_{j+1}\}$. We want the complement of $A_3 \cup A_5 \cup A_7$, which is counted by
$$
3^7 - |A_3| - |A_5| - |A_7| + |A_3 \cap A_5|+ |A_3 \cap A_7|+ |A_5 \cap A_7| - |A_3 \cap A_5 \cap A_7| \\
= 3^7 - 3\cdot3\cdot3^4 + 3\cdot 3 \cdot 3^2 - 3
= 1536
$$
So the answer is $4\cdot 1536 = 2^{11}\cdot 3$.

Yes. So far the only correct answer!

Ohh... It's OK. Somehow I didn't notice the condition 'for all $j∈{3,5,7}$' was already there. Deleted my previous comment.

First attempt:
Well, it seems you have four intervals which need a constant value: $[0,1[$, $[1, 2[$, $[2, 3[$ and $[3, 4]$.
For the first one, you have three choices ($-1$, $0$ and $1$).
For the second one, you have two choices (it can't be same as in the first interval).
For the third one, you have two choices (it can't be same as in the second interval).
For the fourth one, you have two choices (it can't be same as in the third interval).
So, basically the amount of choices equals $3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 24$.
Second attempt:
That first attempt, because instead of cutting the interval into four pieces, I need to do it into ten: $\{ 0 \}$, $]0,1[$, $\{1\}$, $]1, 2[$, $\{2\}$, $]2, 3[$, $\{3\}$, $]3, 4[$ and $\{4\}$. The same reasoning applies but the result becomes $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 3 \cdot 2^8 = 768$.

I believe there is no problem in two consecutive intervals having the same values since we can always make the function DC by setting the integer between them to something else.
for example f((0,1))=f((1,2))=1 and f(1)=-1 makes the function discontinuous.
The answer, as I have mentioned is indeed $2^{11}\cdot 3$. I am on the lookout for a cleaner method now

It's also not required an interval and its endpoint have different values. As long as the endpoint is common to two intervals, it's enough that the value at it differs from at least one of the neighbouring intervals's values.

@FrenzyRipper: are you sure about your eleventh power? My second attempt only covers the eighth power.

You seem to have assumed the function's value on each 'part' of the domain, as you have partitioned it, must be different than that on the previous part. Hence a 'two times two times two...' pattern. But that assumption is wrong. As a counterexample, suppose $f$ equal $0$ on a closed interval $[2,3]$. This makes three consecutive parts all with the same value of $f$. Seems counter-intuitive? But it's enough to assume e.g. $f=1$ on $]1,2[$ and $]3,4[$ and the function becomes discontinuous on both integers, $2$ and $3$, as required.

Let's start from $\{0\}$. You have $3$ values possible at it. Then you can choose one of remaining two in $]0,1[$, which makes $3\cdot 2=6$ functions on $[0,1[$.
Next, you can choose any of $3$ values for the interval's endpoint $\{1\}$, BUT:

if it differs from the value on $]0,1[$, you have three choices possible for $]1,2[$,
and if it equals the value on $]0,1[$, you have only two.

So at the endpoint of an interval you have $2\cdot 3 + 2 = 8$ possibilities for that endpoint and the next interval.
As a result, for $3$ intervals in $[1,4[$ you have $(2\cdot 3 + 2)^3 = 512$ possibilities. Multiply it by a previous partial result and you get  $3\cdot 2 \cdot (2\cdot 3 + 2)^3 = 3072$ functions on $[0,4[$.
Finally, multiply it by $2$ for two choices at the endpoint $\{4\}$, and the result is $3\cdot 2 \cdot (2\cdot 3 + 2)^3 \cdot 2 = 6144$.
In more general terms, let $v=3$ the number of values allowed, and $k=4$ the number of intervals; then $n$ the number of 'valid' functions is
$$\begin{align}
n & = v\cdot (v-1) \cdot ((v-1)\cdot v + (v-1))^{k-1} \cdot (v-1) \\
& = v\cdot (v-1)^2 \cdot ((v-1)\cdot (v+1))^{k-1} \\
& = v\cdot (v-1)^2 \cdot (v^2-1)^{k-1} \end{align}$$
For $v=3$ it makes $$n=3\cdot 2^2 \cdot 8^{k-1} = 3\cdot 2^{3k-1},$$ which, for $k=4$, results in $$n=3\cdot 2^{11}.$$
